# Azure Blob Storage - Delete permissions for folder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

for my Azure Storage Account w/ hierarchical namespace, I've assigned the  `Storage Account Contributor` and `Storage Blob Data Contributor` to my user account:

[image]

Upload / download of blobs and folder works fine, but i can't delete folders. Whenever i try to select a folder over the checkbox and click "Delete" i get this error:

[image]

[image]

Which permission in the Access Control IAM is required for deletion of a folder in Azure Storage account?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Those 2 roles are enough and by giving those 2 roles, I am able to dleete folders too.https://i.imgur.com/ieAeEbQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you don’t have the permission to delete those files, with azure lock service, the administrator can configure this service to prevent users from deleting some files by mistake, you can look about this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/lock-account-resource?tabs=portal

Answer (score 1):

to delete a folder in azure storage acount you need to have the `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/delete` permission. This permission can be granted through the `Storage Blob Data Contributor`, `Storage Blob Data Owner` or the `Storage Account Contributor` roles in the `Access Control (IAM)` settings of the Azure Storage account.
or you can delete all the folder inside the blod you should look a [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/507459/deleting-a-folder-from-blob-storagelo) to delete a folder in a storage account.